# Admin ajax request return 0 with die()

Tags: wp-admin, ajax

So i'm using this configuration for an AJAX call in the administrative area ([like this](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Administration_Side)):

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'ajaxPerNgg' );

function ajaxPerNgg(){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#message").remove();
    jQuery("#errore a#attivo").click(
        function(){
            var data = {
                action: 'my_action'
            };
            jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                if(response == "attivato")
                    jQuery("#errore a#inattivo").attr("id","completato").html("Attivato");
                else
                    jQuery("#errore a#inattivo").attr("id","attivo").html("Attivalo ora");
            });
        }
    );
});
</script>
<?php }

add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');

function my_action_callback() {
    echo 'attivato';
    die();
}
```

It's just a test code, but it always return 0 instead of the string "attivato". It also find the ajax url correctly, without a 404 error.
What is the problem?

Comment: Did you ever get this problem figured out? If so, can you please comment (or accept) the answer that solved your problem? If none of these solved your problem and it *is solved*, could you please add an answer below? Thank you!

Comment: @jmort253 hi, sorry to answer you right now, but at the moment, i still have this problem and i found no solution around the web :'( i'm working on it when i have some spare time; if i find the solution, i'll write here ;)

Comment: Ok, same here. If I figure it out, I'll post. :)  Keep in touch.

Comment: I solved my problem, the suffix of the `wp_ajax_my_action`, the "my_action" part, must match the action used in the jQuery post. I see that yours matches, so that's not the problem in your case. I also have it working from the admin page, which is what you're trying to do. Are you logged in when trying to make this ajax call? Or are you logged out?

Comment: Right. Didn't notice that! ;)

Answer (score 21):

Add this as well: `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback');`. Notice the `nopriv`.

It will solve your problem!

Comment: I fixed this by making sure the suffix of "wp_ajax_SUFFIX" matches the action, so that the action in the jQuery post was also "SUFFIX". However, I didn't need to use nopriv... Not sure if this is the answer to the op's problem, since this is an action that's occurring on the admin page, which pretty much means you're logged in, which suggests you don't need to register a nopriv handler...

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem. Solution:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
```

If you dont add both (with and without nopriv) it will work in either signed in mode or signed out mode only. nopriv is for signed out, the other is for signed in.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is your problem, but I was getting a response of just "0" and it took me the longest time to figure it out.  Aside from making sure you put `exit` or `die` at the end of your php function, I found out that you have to put your `add_action('wp_ajax_...` bit at the top level of your plugin.  I had it nested inside my `admin_menu` hook, which didn't work.  I'm not sure if your code above is part of an include inside a function from your top level plugin php file (like mine was).

Comment: The same problem here.. Not sure how to fix this kind of issue, since we sometimes need to put the ajax response inside or at the end part of codes.